# Como puedo compara una un String-array

Tags: android, android-studio, array, string

```
else if (pregunta1.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("2.-Coloque la el comando para entrar a la terminal de PowerShell")){
            AlertDialog.Builder ad=new AlertDialog.Builder(Matematicas.this);
            ad.setTitle("Indique la respuesta correcta");
            ad.setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.Pregunta2, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(Matematicas.this, "" + which, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
            });
            ad.setPositiveButton("confirmar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                    String[] esto=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Pregunta2);


                    if (esto.toString().equals("A)PowerShell"))
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "si", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            ad.show();
```

Comment: comparas con un spinner?

Comment: No,Lo compraro en un AlertDialog

Comment: que comparas? un textView? spinner? listView? o solo un Array?

Comment: lo compraro en un Array, En el AlertDialog Parese el String-array, y cuando se selecciona una opcion con un Radio Button es ahi donde comparo con el mismo String-array

Comment: entonces "A)PowerShell" es el texto de un radio button?

Comment: si, es el texto de un radio button que mande a llamar desde String-array

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para comparar el texto de un radio button, con un string, se usa getText:

```
 if(radiobutton.getText().equals("texto"))
```

Para compararlo con un String array usa un for, en este caso si algunos
de los elementos del array (esto) coincide con el texto del radio button:

```
 for(int i=0; i<esto.length ; i++) {
        if (esto[i].equals(tuRadioButton.getText()) ) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "si", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```